# How to make this progress bar start animating when scroll down to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this animated progress bar. I'd like to ask if it possible the progress bar to start animating when I scroll down to it?

I know I should use javascript to make it work on scroll but didn't know how. I will appreciate any help with that.

```css
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  animation: animate-positive 6s;
}

.progress .progress-value {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: right;
}

.progress .progressbar-title {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-positive {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-positive {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="background:#7f7e7d;">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width:80%; background: #000000;">
    <div class="progress-value">80%</div>
    <div class="progressbar-title">Progress</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the css class on the element when the scroll down is started

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by checking if the progress bar is in viewport. Once it is in the view port you can use jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to start the animation.
In folloing code I have replace all your CSS animation and used jQuery animate.

```js
function isInViewport($elem) {
 let elementTop = $elem.offset().top;
 let elementBottom = elementTop + $elem.outerHeight();
 let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
 return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
}
let $progress = $(".progress");
let $progressBar = $progress.children(".progress-bar");
let maxVal = parseInt($(".progress-value").text());
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if (isInViewport($progress)) {
  $progressBar.animate(
   {
    width: maxVal + "%"
   },
   1000
  );
 }
});
```

```css
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.progress-bar {
  background: #000;
}

.progress .progress-value {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: right;
}

.progress .progressbar-title {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:500px; background: red; color:#fff;"> 
 This div pushes slider below viewPort. Scroll down to see slider
</div>
<div class="progress" style="background:#7f7e7d;">
 <div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-value">100%</div>
  <div class="progressbar-title">Progress</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I thank you as your answer and code given is correct Sir.

Comment: @viper1, you can mark it as the answer if it is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    if($("body").scrollTop() === 500){
        $(window).off("scroll");
        // Execute your animation here
    }
}
```

This line:

```
$(window).off("scroll");
```

removes the scroll event handler, as I am assuming you only want this to fire once.

I hope this will give you something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this library](https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view) when I need to add animation when scroll down. I think you can add some class or id to div when this block is visible.